# Filter page datasource based on record selection

Tags: google-app-maker

I seem to be struggling with this. I am working on a project management app in Google App Maker. I am using SQL data models. The portion of the app I am having trouble with is several project detail pages linked with a project list page. I have no trouble going from the project list page to the first project detail page.

I have a table widget in the project list page, and the onClick code for a table row is:

```
    app.datasources.Projects.selectKey(widget.datasource.item._key);
    app.showPage(app.pages.ProjectPage);
```

This filters the first detail page with the primary key of the record in focus. No problem here. When I want to navigate the next detail page that has a different datasource (but I still need to filter using the same primary key) I am struggling.

If someone can guide me in making a button in the first detail page that when clicked gets the _key of the project loaded in that current page and filters another detail page for the same project in focus, (using another data model, let's call it ProjectBudgetPage for example) I would really appreciate the help.

This was one my latest attempts at navigation to other detail pages within a project, this was for an onClick event:

```
     var widgets = widget.parent.descendants;
     var projectID = widgets.HiddenProjectID.text;
     var projectDataSource = app.datasources.ProjectBudgetView.item;
     projectDataSource = projectID;
     app.showPage(app.pages.ProjectInfoPage);
```

which results in: `(TypeError) : Cannot read property '__gwt_instance' of undefined
at HeaderProjectTabs.HeaderContainer.InfoTabButton.onClick:5:5`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set current item in App Maker datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104914/how-to-set-current-item-in-app-maker-datasource)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood properly but I suggest that you start by checking this official App Maker template available here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/partner-management/ which provides a ready-to-run app you can use to manage an internal list of partners, but you can also customize it with your own needs. I recently used most of the UI and logic of this template and I was able to integrate it with SQL data models and it works really great.

I noticed that for this template they are saving the (widget.datasource.item._key) to a Page custom property which you can access afterwards. Custom properties are page-level properties that store data for a single user session. Custom properties are useful when you need to bind properties of multiple widgets to a single value. More info available here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties

In your scenario, you can create a new custom property (string) inside your ProjectInfoPage and then you can add a script to the button onClick event in your ProjectPage to save the _key or any other item to a page property. For example:

```
app.pages.ProjectInfoPage.properties.ProjectKey = widget.datasource.item._key;
app.showDialog(app.pages.ProjectInfoPage);
```

Then you can get the “ProjectKey” property by adding this to the onAttach event in your ProjectInfoPage:

```
var key = app.pages.ProjectInfoPage.properties.ProjectKey;
…
```

In the onAttach event you can filter the new model or pass the property values to a server script. I believe there are other approaches but I hope this helps!