# How to set current item in App Maker datasource?

Tags: google-app-maker

This seems basic but I can't seem to figure out how to manually set the current item to work with from the datasource?

To illustrate: I have a table and I notice that when I select a row to edit a field, the item of that row becomes the current item, so if I have a link on that row to Navigate to a page, the row of the item selected will be the datasource.item for the navigated page.

However, I also notice that if I just hover over a row, without selecting to edit a field, if then I click on a link to Navigate to a page, it loads the data of whatever row was previously selected/edited. Therefore I'm wondering how to make it so that just on a mouse:over (or click on the shortcut without a prior click on another field in the row) the datasource.item will update to the the row the mouse has gone over instead of requiring to edit a field on the row first. I hope that makes sense.

Assistance is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Why it happens:

```
AM code: generate button click event
User code: handle button's click event
User code: navigate user to different page
AM code: destroy DOM of current page
AM code: build DOM for new page
-- dead code after this line
AM code: row click event handler
AM code: change datasource's current item
```

Row's click event handler never gets control, because row is destroyed by user's code.

What [Morfinismo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5983596/morfinismo)'s solution does?

```
AM code: generate button click event
User code: handle button's click event
AM code: row click event handler
AM code: change datasource's current item
-- moved lines
User code: navigate user to different page
AM code: destroy DOM of current page
AM code: build DOM for new page
```

Here are more tech details: [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

In App Maker this problem can be solved with

1. [setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50105054/454137)
2. Force current item update in user code

```javascript
// button's onClick event handler
app.datasource.ListDatasource.selectKey(widget.datasource.item._key);
```

3. [CustomProperties](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties)

```javascript
// button's onClick event handler
app.pages.ShowMeNext.properties.Key = widget.datasource.item._key;
app.showPage(app.pages.ShowMeNext);

// next page's onAttach event handler
app.datasources.RecordDatasource.filters._key._equals = app.currentPage.properties.Key;
app.datasources.RecordDatasource.load();
```

4. [URL parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url) and [history](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/history) - this approach is used in most [template apps](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/), because it also implements deep linking on some extent.

```javascript
// button's onClick event handler
var params = {
               key: widget.datasource.item._key
             };
var page = app.pages.ShowMeNext;
app.showPage(page);
google.script.history.replace(null, params, page.name);

// next page's onAttach event handler
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
  app.datasources.RecordDatasource.filters._key._equals = location.parameters.key;
});
```

5. Passing value between pages using global scope

```javascript
// button's onClick event handler
window.key = widget.datasource.item._key;

// next page's onAttach event handler
app.datasources.RecordDatasource.filters._key._equals = window.key;
```

**ListDatasource** - list/grid/table datasource

**RecordDatasource** - datasource dedicated for a specific record (single-record datasource)

Comment: Interesting analysis. Now I know what happens under the hood. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly thorough reply and description of other alternatives!

Answer (score 3):

Use a timeout function. This happens because it takes some time for appmaker to change the item in the datasource. You can use something like this on the **onClick** event handler of the button or link that will take you to the other page:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  app.showPage(app.pages.pageToNavigate);
},200);
```

That should take care of the issue. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and for the quick and simple solution!